# Save all xml to csv without xml atributes

Tags: xml, vba, csv, type-conversion

I have a lot of xml format file in folder.
I want to extract specific data from them.
I wrote a macros to get what I want, but from xml I'm not able to take specific data.

I try to save file as csv and macro works.

But I save to csv like file-->save as..
If I try to convert files to csv it converts with all attributes from xlm file..

How I can convert all xml files at once to get csv files only with data what I need, without attributes..?

```
Public Sub ConvertXmlToXlsx()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

xmlFolder = "C:\Users\valesk1\Desktop\Calibration_\test\LOG\"
convFolder = "C:\Users\valesk1\Desktop\Calibration_\test\LOG\csv\"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(xmlFolder)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase(Right(objFile.Name, Len(XML))) = UCase(XML) Then
        NewFileName = convFolder & objFile.Name & ".csv"

        Workbooks.OpenXML (objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name), LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

    End If
Next objFile

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

I would like to convert xml to csv without any attributes, only results

Comment: I don't think You can achieve that by only saving that in chosen format file. After opening the .csv file to try to seek for tags/ specific words with for example InStr() function and with found values fill the table.

Comment: well it works if I open xml file and save it as csv, I can do it with few Files but I have thousands..

Comment: Oh I actually did it, I edit this line and it works     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8

Comment: My bad, that's why i love stack, everyday I am learning new stuff. Thanks for that Skirmante.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ConvertXmlToXlsx()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

xmlFolder = "C:\Users\valesk1\Desktop\Calibration_\test\LOG\"
convFolder = "C:\Users\valesk1\Desktop\Calibration_\test\LOG\csv\"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(xmlFolder)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase(Right(objFile.Name, Len(XML))) = UCase(XML) Then
        NewFileName = convFolder & objFile.Name & ".csv"

        Workbooks.OpenXML (objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name), LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

    End If
Next objFile

End Sub
```